# Parsing returned json from Django async rest call

Tags: json, django, rest

I am in process of learning Django to build a smaller application that consumes a swagger REST API.
When I am testing the API, I get a lot of JSON output, that I need to take, filter(change values) and send back via PUT, POST (typical stuff.)

I have tried the async client sessions with return of json_response like this:

```
async def get_some_jsonrest_value_back(response):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://example.com',
            headers={'X-API-KEY':' fdfsdfdfff', 'Content-Type':'application/json'},
            json={}) as resp: 
            response = await resp.json() 
            return json_response(response, text=None, body=None, status=200, reason=None,
              headers=None, content_type='application/json')
```

I do get the values like these:

```
{
  "key1": "values1",
  "key2": {
    "@subkey1": "54534543",
    "@subkey2": "fdsfdsfdsf",
    "subkey3": [
      "fdsfsdfdsf"
    ],
    "subkey4": "fdfsdfds",
    "subkey5": "8594593489"
  },
  "key3": "8594859438594385943",
  "key4": "kfdlskfldsk"
}
```

And the values grow, with many sections of that JSON output. There can be like hundreds of those JSONs.

My question would be , if someone could point me to some examples of django code, which consumes API, returnes the JSON values and for an example takes out only the subkeys from 1 to 5 (like in json example in output). After that it changes the values and returns back to the external REST API via POST/PUT.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I am also aware of the DRF serializer that saves to the database, but I would like to avoid to save the data into a local database (personal data) and still able to parse/omit/change/resend JSONs that I get from the REST CALLS and want to send back.

Comment: Maybe I could achieve this with django-redis, just to cache locally and restart the redis service every hour to loose all the data and not save it inside a database (would like to have no PII data in a database).